# How to convert JSON to XML in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

With JSON support, I'm able to call a web service. Orbeon will internally change the JSON to XML. Question is, inside the XML, there is a node element that contains JSON string. How do I convert that into XML and assign it an variable(so I can use XPath for further query)? Is there any Orbeon converter that can be called?

Example of instance data after submission to the web service:

```
<json type="object"> 
   <data>
   { "name": "Mark", "age": 21 }
   </data>
 </json>
```

Comment: So you receive JSON which itself contains JSON?

Comment: Yes, exactly; In addition, I noticed there is Converter.jsonStringToXml method in  ConverterTest. Wonder how to call this method from orbeon form which might solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not documented, and is subject to change, you could use the native Scala function from XPath:

```
converter:jsonStringToXml(instance('json'))
```

Here is a full example:

```
<xh:html
    xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xh:head>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance id="json">
                <json type="object">
                   <data>{ "name": "Mark", "age": 21 }</data>
                 </json>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <xf:output
            xmlns:converter="org.orbeon.oxf.json.Converter"
            value="
                xxf:serialize(
                    converter:jsonStringToXml(instance('json')/data),
                    'xml'
                )"/>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

In Orbeon Forms 2016.3, we [plan to include](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2942) XPath functions to do this.

Comment: Great to know it'll be supported in upcoming release, thanks!

Comment: Documentation for the functions added in 2016.3: https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-json.html