# Check if JSON string in Orbeon repeating grid contains a specific value

Tags: json, xpath, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

Working with the repeating grids through the form builder.

I have a custom control that has a string value represented in json.

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "File",
    "itemID": "12345",
    "name": "Annual Summary",
    "parentFolderID": "fileID",
    "owner": "Owner",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2016-10-17 22:48:05Z"
  }
}
```

In the controls outside of the repeating grid, i need to check if **name = "Annual Summary"**

Previously, i had a drop down control and using Calculated Value **$dropdownControl = "Annual Summary"** it was able to return true if any of the repeated rows contained the value. My understanding is that using the **=** operator, it will validate against all rows.

Now with the json output of the control, I am attempting to use

```
contains($jsonStringValue, 'Annual Summary')
```

However, this only works with one entry and will be null if there are multiple rows.

2 questions:

1. How would validate whether "Annual Summary" (or any other text) is present within **any of the repeated rows**?
2. Is there any way to navigate the json or parse it to XML and navigate it?

Constraint:

- within the Calculated Value or Visibility fields within form builder
- manipulating the source that is generated by the form builder

Comment: Did you get to try the solution provided?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to parse the JSON string first. See also this [other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735209/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-orbeon/39753257#39753257).

Until Orbeon Forms 2016.3 is released, you would write:

```
(
    for $v in $jsonStringValue
    return converter:jsonStringToXml($v)
)//name = 'Annual Summary'
```

With the above, you also need to scope the namespace:

```
xmlns:converter="org.orbeon.oxf.json.Converter"
```

Once Orbeon Forms 2016.3 is released you can switch to:

```
$jsonStringValue/xxf:json-to-xml()//name = 'Annual Summary'
```